# removing history points from browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-ajax

can we remove history points created in web browser.

or is it possible not add history point when a sample link "some link"
is clicked and url in browser changed

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot remove items from the browser history, but you can load a new document into the window and *bypass* the history with javascript.  This is done with the [replace() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.location#Methods) of location objects

```
top.location.replace( newUrl );
```

Comment: Didn't get this to work when only the anchor part of the URL changed. At least Safari 5 leaves the anchor part away when location.replace is called.

Answer (score 4):

Browser's history belongs to the user, not to your application (client or serverside). There is no way to access it through javascript and this is a very good thing.

Comment: take a case of gmail, log into it,make sure stay sign is checked,close browser and  again open gmail, now  address in browser will change many time and will finally land at your mail box but none of those points are accessible through back button. how do they do it.

Comment: @Praveen Prasad the requests are probably redirects and hence don't show up browser history.